# Negative Sign in Deduction Amount on Stripe Invoice Download Link

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription, invoice, laravel-cashier

I'm working with the Stripe API, and when I receive a link to download an invoice, the deduction amount is displayed with a negative sign. I would like to format or handle this in a way that the negative sign is not included.

Here's an example of the data I'm dealing with:

description                                       quantity                              amount
Unused time on 5 × abc plan
after 27 Dec 2023
Dec 27, 2023                                         5                                  -$10,566.65

Is there a way to customize the formatting or retrieve the amount without the negative sign when obtaining an invoice download link from Stripe?

I'm using the [specific programming language or library you're working with, e.g., Python, JavaScript].
I've checked the relevant documentation on Stripe but couldn't find a clear solution to this issue.
I've also reviewed my subscription settings and billing logic to ensure there are no unintended negative adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

All Invoice settings are accessible in the Stripe dashboard [here](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/invoice?tab=general). And there's no option to remove or replace the negative sign of deductions.

The only way to achieve what you want with Stripe would be to create and design your own invoice.

Comment: question context is not remove negative sign, he just want to replace negative sign with other sign like `-$100` to `(100)`.

Comment: Not possible either, I edited my answer to clarify this.